# Dynamic memory allocation function for string until newline

Tags: string, pointers, memory, dynamic, allocation

Earlier i just tried to do this function for allocating memory for a string of unknown length (that is read character by character, until newline is encountered).

Now, my question is about the allocated memory for my string (named s) release.
I tried to do this using free(s). The problem is that i do not know where should i write it..

if i write it in the function before the "return s", then, obvious it will return an unallocated pointer.

if i write it in the function after the "return s", i don't think it will have an effect, right? As it will never be released since s was returned in main().

What should i do or think about this situation?

This is what i got:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Returns dynamic allocated string(read until the '\n' aka. newline character)
char* input_string_line()
{   char *s,*aux,c;                     //*s(string pointer),*aux(auxiliary string pointer),c(the characters that are read)
    int len;                            //len(actual length of the string)
    s=malloc(sizeof(char));             //firstly, allocation memory for 1 byte(8 bites), for the null character
    if (!s)                             //verification if the memory can be allocated, if not possible then the program exits
    {   printf("ERROR: Memory allocation failure (string).\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    s[0] = 0;                           //NULL character for string ending
    len = 0;                            //the length of the string at the beginning is 0(without considering the NULL character at the end)
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')     //reading character by character until newline
    {   aux = realloc(s, len + 2);      //reallocation memory for the next read character in a new auxiliary string(same as the old string, this time having memory for a new character to be added)
        if (!aux)                       //verification if the reallocation can succed: if not possible then the program exits
        {   free(s);
            printf("ERROR: Memory allocation failure (auxiliary string).\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
        else s = aux;                   //if succeded, then the string becomes the auxiliary string
        s[len] = c;                     //the character with the [len] index will be assigned the value of the read character
        s[len+1] = 0;                   //NULL character for string ending
        len++;  }                       //length increments by one each time a new character is added to the string
    return s;
    free(s);                        
}

int main()
{ printf("%s",input_string_line());
return 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the nature or your input_string_line() function, the only place where you should free your pointer is in main function. Any other place will produce and invalid pointer or will result in a memory leak.

```
int main()
{ 
  char* s = input_string_line();
  printf("%s",s);
  free(s);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about if i just print the string as i did. Do i still have to free my pointer? case: `printf("%s",input_string_line());`

Comment: Yes you have to free it. the C/C++ does not have garbage collector. Whatever you allocate you should free. Otherwise you will get memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How can i do that?!

Comment: See example. You keep a reference to pointer returned by input_string_line() , you use that pointer to print the values and later when you don't need it anymore you will free it.

Comment: Ok, but if i don't keep a reference to that pointer, and i use only the printf to the function? Will the memory remain occupied? How do i free it then?

Comment: If you don't keep a reference to your pointer ,you will not be able to free your memory and will get memory leaks